# Is it possible to generate an .msi bundle from an aspnet core web application?

Tags: c#, wix

So the current situation is, a client will download an .msi bundle generated from wix, perform the install and enter some specific configuration details afterwards into the application (a windows service/console).

I was looking to streamline this process so all the client has to do is run the installer (no configuration needed), so I was wondering if anyone had any experience with a similar situation.

This is how i image the workflow would run.

User logs into multi-tenant web application => User clicks a download button => Web server collects tenant information => Web server passes configuration into wix (as a build parameter?) => msi is generated with the configuration embeded => User downloads the generated .msi and the world keeps spinning.

Now there are a few things i am unsure of, so here are my questions.

1. How would you go about running the wix installer from the web application? It's written in C# so would it just launch a cmd window and run msbuild?
2. If 1. is possible, how would it look/function in Visual Studio. I'm assuming the installer project/installer asset project would both need to be in the build output of the web application, is it possible to copy the raw files into the output? <= is that even a good practice?

It just doesn't seem practical to me, so if anyone has any suggestions on how this can be accomplished, either how I described above or any other methods then I am open to ideas!

Just to clarify, the main goal is to "generate a windows installer at runtime with a tenant configuration embedded"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it from C# for sure. Take a look at the Wix extensions for CakeBuild for example: https://github.com/cake-build/cake/tree/33b83fdbc24a7d3d1bafc4cd7c7df0a204162e3b/src/Cake.Common/Tools/WiX

As to packaging 'content' files up with your web application you can do that too, the wix project files are no different than any other asset as far as the website is concerned.

Also, to run processes from a dot net application there's a bunch of work to do around redirecting and logging the output, you may wish to look into some of the process handling packages on Nuget that can do this for you.

Performance may be an issue for you, plus ways to secure the downloadable MSI in case you only want one user to get it. You may also need to look into code signing if you aren't already. Other than that it should be fairly straightforward.

Comment: Thanks Ian, i use CakeBuild in my build script anyway so this makes perfect sense. As for the actual deployment, am i right in thinking that as part of the build process, the Windows Service artifact (.exe, .dlls etc) would have be copied to the Web Project output, ready to be used by the wix project files? or would there be another method to accomplishing this?

Comment: @tjackadams I don't think you'd need to copy them there, one MSI can handle multiple Feature definitions and/or Directory definitions installing stuff into different places and you can pull files from anywhere.